# android mediaplayer double play

Tags: android, stream, double, audio-player, android-music-player

I have a problem. This is stream player it is playing fine but when I start play, change app and again start player app the stop button is disabled.
If I pressing play again - it start plaing double music and I cannot stop first stream playing.

In short: I need one app and one sound and possibility to stop sound (without double playing)

```
import com.erkutaras.media.audio.url.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class StreamAudioFromUrlSampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{
    private Button btn_play,
                    btn_pause,
                    btn_stop;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int lengthOfAudio;
    private final String URL = "http://play.org.ua:8000/";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable r = new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekProgress();                   
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        btn_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        btn_play.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
        btn_pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        btn_stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);

        seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            SeekBar tmpSeekBar = (SeekBar)v;
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((lengthOfAudio / 100) * tmpSeekBar.getProgress() );
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            lengthOfAudio = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_play:
            playAudio();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_pause:
            pauseAudio();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_stop:
            stopAudio();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        updateSeekProgress();
    }

    private void updateSeekProgress() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            seekBar.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / lengthOfAudio) * 100));
            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        }
    }

    private void stopAudio() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    private void pauseAudio() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void playAudio() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        btn_play.setEnabled(false);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(true);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you get the sollution..? I also get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your `OnClick()` method add `if`:

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
  //mediaPlayer.pause; //or what you want instead double play
}
else
{
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately! Because when I change orientation to landscape again stop botton is disabled, only play button is enabled. If I pressing PLAY - again have double music playing...but how to save connect with first started stream and control it???

Comment: @Artem Use AsyncTask instead Runnable() !

Comment: maybe the best way to lunch music in service and control it from app ?